# RxSwift , how to return error with .code?

Tags: ios, swift

```
func loginClicked(){
   self.networkingSession.deviceRegister().map { _ in}
       .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
       .subscribe(onSuccess: { [weak self] _ in
          self?.didSignIn.onNext(())
        },onError: { [weak self] err in
          print(">>>>>>> What \(err.localizedDescription)")
          self?.didFailSignIn.onNext(err)
      })
      .disposed(by: disposeBag)
  }
```

Inside my   `func deviceRegister() -> Single<DeviceRegisterResponse>`, I'm returning .failure with 2 error types:

```
 single(.error(NSError(domain: "Fail Case A",code: 999, userInfo: nil)))
 single(.error(NSError(domain: "Fail Case B",code: 111, userInfo: nil)))
```

I want to indicate an error at `onError`, and create a switch condition for `case A` and `case B`.

Unfortunately , I can't find any information inside err except `err.localizedDescription`.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your `err` to `NSError`. It has a `code` property.

```
let err1 = err as NSError
print(err.code)
```

You are sending the `NSError`, but in the chain it's abstracted to the `Error`. So, upon receiving, you can convert it back to the `NSError`. Hope this helps.